# Sharelatex error ''Project too large This project has to much text,.."

Tags: errors, sharelatex

i'm working on sharelatex with a book with lots of pages (about 1000),

i usually compile each chapter separately of course,
but even so, at some point it just stops compiling and gives me the following error

''Project too large This project has to much text, please try and reduce it''

After that, whatever i try, fails. I try with previous chapters that had no errors but still fails.

Do you have any ideas why this happens? Is it the browser's issue(i tried with chrome and safari). Or share latex just crushes?

Comment: This is really an issue with ShareLaTeX, not LaTeX itself: one for their help.

Comment: This will be because there is too much text in the project. It needs to be deleted not commented out. The common cause is a massive style file or big .bib file. If you still have problems email support.

Comment: For me, there were many tikz files on a folder (Not even using them all but thought it was no harm).